# Android: AsynchTask fails when called from onRestoreInstanceState()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app who's UI takes a little work to build (has to process some stuff).  So, I build the UI using an AsynchTask (it shows a progress dialog while doing some background processing, then does the UI update).  I would like to be able to call this AsynchTask from OnRestoreInstanceState(), so that I can rebuild the UI on a rotation.  However, when I call  MyAsynchTask.execute() from the onRestorInstanceState() method, I get the below exception:

```
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e70368 that was originally added here
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-05 12:28:45.194: ERROR/WindowManager(409):     at com.MyClass$MyAsynchTask.onPreExecute(MyClass.java:428)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Make your `AsyncTask` a static inner class or a regular full Java class.

Step #2: Manually associate the activity the task should work with via a constructor parameter, held in a data member of the task.

Step #3: Return the task object from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`

Step #4: In `onCreate()` of the new activity instance, get the existing task object via `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` and manually re-associate the activity the task should work with via a setter method.

Step #4: If needed, modify `onPostExecute()` to not reference the activity.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationAsync) demonstrating this flow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I implemented the example you gave, but now I get this error when I try to execute my AsynchTask from my onRestore method:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once).... at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:383)

Comment: @ab11: You cannot re-execute tasks. If you executed the task in the old activity, you do not need to re-execute it in the new activity.

Comment: My task runs to process some stuff into a (currently) unserializable object, which is then used to create the UI.  So on a rotate, this object is lost (because I can't currently serialize it into the stored bundle) which is why I want to re-execute my AsynchTask, to restore it.  I can simply create a new instance of my AsynchTask (as opposed to using a member variable, as in your example).  But even if I do this and pass it this.MyActivity as a parameter of the construction, I still get the original "window has leaked" exception.

Comment: @ab11: "So on a rotate, this object is lost" -- use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` (see step #3).

Comment: Thanks.  While looking in to how I should use that method, it became apparent that I should be onConfigurationChanged(), so that I don't have to worry about storing and recreating these object.

Comment: @ab11: Google really does not recommend that except in unusual cases, like 3D games or camera previews.

Comment: Ok.  I can't find anything about why it is not recommended, can I trouble you for a link. So I'm better off just storing anything i want in the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method, and then retrieving it in onResume().  If so, a few quick questions: how do i know that the onResume is a result of a rotation (as opposed to my application was paused)? this is important, because how do i know that the object which I retrieve is still valid (changes might have occured between the last rotate and the current pause?