# Android AsyncTask onPreExecute not called indeterminantly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that is supposed to show a progress bar while it uploads some stuff via Internet. Sometimes it works like a charm and sometimes it does not show any progress bar. Here is the code:

```
public class Upload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "wait...", "", true, true);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //upload stuff
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        Intent next = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(next);
        }
    }
}
```

The doInBackground and onPostExecute work always, and sometimes altogether it works like a charm. But sometimes, there is no progress bar while it is uploading. Is this a race condition? I do not think so, but I cannot find any explanation.

Comment: Is your `AsyncTask` an inner class of your `Activity` or a separate class?

Comment: It is an inner class. Implementing like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607228/android-asynchtask-fails-when-called-from-onrestoreinstancestate] results in a null pointer in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @JerecTheSith look for a leaked activity exception in your logcat, and try not to reference anything in your asynctask. Apart from this, progress bar shows up fine right now for me, except on Galaxy S3s. I to this day have not learned the cause, and perhaps I never will.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the object twice in the class. The `ProgressDialog.show` already returns a created `ProgressDialog` object, but you have instantiated it first at the top. The `ProgressDialog` should be instantiated once, so try removing the instantiation at the top and try again, like so:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "wait...", "", true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because void parameter that causes that problem. Just try to use Integer as your parameters.:

```
public class Upload extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
```